# How to avoid ScollPane in Stage and GestureListerner to fling at same time

Tags: libgdx

I have a scrollpane in stage and an own define GestureListerner ( for detecting screen fling ), combining both with inputMultiplexer.

However, when i am scrolling my scrollpane, i dont want my gestureListerner to be triggered. How can I achieve that?

Comment: IIRC the multiplexer will trigger the listener methods in the order they were added. So whichever listener you added first will get triggered first. The listeners also returns a boolean which dictates whether the action was handled. So if the scrollpane listener returns true it will not propagate down into the gesture listener.

Comment: Thank you. Was having problem of finding and overwriting scollpane listerner to return true value. I solve this by adding new eventListerner and return true value, just like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211992/scroll-listener-on-scroll-pane-libgdx].  Not sure if this is the proper way of achieving the result.

Comment: There's no other way, unfortunately. I wish there were less private members in the Scene2d Actors, but protected instead so subclasses could overwrite the behaviour.

Comment: Noted. Thanks !!